# Spectrum: Products

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Given a unital C*-algebra $1\in\mathcal{A}$.

For the spectrum of products:
$$\sigma(AB)\cup\{0\}=\sigma(BA)\cup\{0\}$$
How can I find an example that shows 
that zero must be indeed taken out?

Obviously, they must not commute. 
So the natural choice will be matrices. 
But all matrices I tried out didn't work. 
Also taking ladder operators seem to fail?

What would be the idea behind such a recipe? 
(Besides I'm not asking for a specific example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Shirley's answer, you will not find such matrices (if you want them square, i.e. in a C$^*$-algebra). For square matrices $A,B$, the two matrices $AB$ and $BA $ have the same eigenvalues (counting multiplicities). If you allow rectangular matrices for the question, you can take 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ \ \ B=A^T. 
$$
Then $BA=1$, with spectrum $\{1\}$, and $AB=E_{11}$ has spectrum $\{0,1\}$.

---

Here is a proof of the fact that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues (counting multiplicities) when both $A$ and $B$ are square. Let
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix} I&A\\ 0&I\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to see that $M$ is invertible and its inverse is $$
M^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} I&-A\\ 0&I\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then a straightforward computation shows that 
$$
M^{-1}\,\begin{bmatrix} AB&0\\ B&0\end{bmatrix}\,M
=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\ B& BA\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So the two matrices above are similar, and in particular they have the same characteristic polynomial. They have, respectively, characteristic polynomials $$P_1(t)=t^n\,P_{AB}(t),\ \ \ \ P_2(t)=t^n\,P_{BA}(t).$$
Thus $P_{AB}(t)=P_{BA}(t)$ and so $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues with the same multiplicities.

Comment: Ooooh that is surprising. So there are no square matrices??? How would one prove that?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Great trick!!!! :D (+1)

Comment: Aha so is the reason: In finite dimensional algebras the spectrum is provided by a characteristic polynomial??

Comment: So it is an interplay between spectrum and polynomial: As the total spectra agree the total polynomial agree. Whence their partial polynomial agree. As the partial polynomial agree the partial spectra agree. Concluding the assertion.

Comment: Yes. In finite dimension, $\lambda I-T$ fails to be invertible if and only if $\det(\lambda I-T)=0$, so the spectrum consists precisely of the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ and consider the unilateral shift $S$. It's an isometry, so $S^*S=I$ is invertible and $0$ is not in the spectrum. But $SS^*$ is not invertible (it's not surjective), so $0\in \sigma(SS^*)$

Comment: The example is very nice too!!! :) (+1)